# Size of structure (C)

Tags: pointers, struct

```
Could anyone explain me output of this code:

    struct X {struct X *p; short a, *b;};
    struct X x, *p=&x;
    printf("0:%x\n", p);
    printf("1:%x\n", sizeof(*p));
    printf("2:%x\n", &p->a);
    printf("3:%x\n", &p->b);
    printf("4:%x\n", ++p);
    printf("5:%x\n", p-&x);
    printf("6:%x\n", &x-p);
```

Output is

[image]

Why is size of *p =18 ?
Other lines also confuse me.
Thx

Comment: "Why is size of *p =18" - I'm guessing you're running this on a 64-bit machine? So it's two 8-byte pointers and a 2-byte short.

Comment: I'm also surprised, especially after checking `offsetof(struct X, b)` which was indeed 10 as the size of 18 seemed to imply. Shouldn't it be aligned?

Answer (score 0):

three remarks:

1. lines 1:1  and 2:8 at the output end are mistake, not related with given code
2. So it is 8 + 2 + 8 = 18, so it seems there is not aligment here. Don't know why... ?
3. Points 2. 3. and 4. are simple, but don't know why 5. and 6.  p-&x  and  &x-p have different results...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).